# how to omit the - in the string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this:

```
string Fname = name - shiva;
```

While assigning to the other string I need remove the `-` in between.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: and what language is this? It sure isn't javascript as it has no typed variables..

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean that you have something like this:

```
string Fname = "name - shiva";
```

In any case, try:

```
myString.replace("-", "")
```

You can customize as needed to meet your needs...

Comment: The problem I am getting is when I am trying to assing the title to the Jquery grid its not displying the grid.. If I hide title then its displaying.. 

Thanks

Comment: OK, that was completely unclear from your question. You need to ask clear, straightforward questions if you expect to get meaningful answers. In any case, if you post your actual code and explain things a bit more, we may be able to help you...

Comment: That is possibly the most unintentionally hilarious misspelling of assign that I've ever seen.

Comment: @Doresoom - What makes you think it was mis-spelled!  :P